# Why do I get "Certificate has not been installed to device yet" error after updating Samsung Gear 2 in Tizen Wearable SDK?

Tags: certificate, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-web-app, samsung-galaxy-gear

I'm developing a Tizen Wearable app with a Samsung Gear 2.  I started developing the app before I had paired the watch to a phone and it was working fine.  I got the certificate and device profile files from Samsung, installed them, and was able to debug/develop my code no problem.

Today I connected the Gear 2 to a Samsung Galaxy S5.  It forced an update to the Gear 2.  Now when I try to install/debug the app from the Tizen Wearable SDK, I get the error `Certificate has not been installed to device yet. Please perform 'permit to install applications' of the context menu in Connection Explorer.`

[image: Certificate has not been installed to device yet error]

When I perform the "Permit to install applications" action, I get another error - "There is no certificate for the selected device.  Please update your certificate":

[image: No certificate for selected device error]

I've deleted and regenerated my author CSR/keys and device profile files twice, getting new ones from Samsung, but still get the same errors.  Stumped!  Any tips much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the problem was that I was creating my device profile with Samsung incorrectly.  I was using the number that showed up in the Connection Explorer (e.g. 5f9931ffxxxxxxx) instead of the actual DUID (e.g. Oc4wavwxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=). I'm not sure how the device profile I was previously using ever worked!  You can find the DUID by right-clicking on the device in Connection Explorer and going to properties.  Once I created and installed a new device profile with the correct DUID, I was able to successfully perform the "Permit to install applications" action - presumably this installs the certificate.

Comment: How do you add a DUID to an existing distributor certificate? When I created mine I just added the DUID of the emulator, now I want to deploy to a real tv

Comment: I haven't been able to add new DUID's to existing certificates, I've had to just recreate a new certificate every time I want to add DUIDs.

Answer (score 0):

When you paired the device to the second phone, it cleared all user space memory, including the device certificate that is written to /home/developer. All you should have to do is reconnect your Gear to your PC and reinstall the certificate.